# Accessing Graph API using Python <401> Error Code

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I am having trouble accessing Microsoft graph after receiving a token from /token. I'm including photos of the Azure AD Application Setup as well as code. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I am able to receive a bearer token from Microsoft, but it is returning <401> Invalid Audience

I cannot yet post images, but I have the application permissions set up in Azure AD following microsoft documentation as well as adding an App Role with User.Read.All.

`

```
myBody = {
        'client_id':'<clientID>',
        'scope':['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'],
        'client_secret':'<client secret>',
        'grant_type':'client_credentials'
    }
    token = requests.post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/{myTenant}/oauth2/token',myBody)
    token = token.json()
    newToken = token['access_token']
    myHeaders = {'Content-type':'application/json','Authorization':f'Bearer {newToken}'}
    
    users = requests.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users',headers=myHeaders)
    users = users.json()
```

`

I've been googling for days. I have tried multiple libraries unsuccessfully. This gets me the furthest in the process, but I've been stopped by the 401 error.

I have added 'Host':'graph.microsoft.com' to the headers as well as made adjustments based on other articles to try and make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try by using tenantId "common" ,
and use POST login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

please see the docs for more info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#token-request

[image]

Hope this helps

Thanks